# framework not found CoreServices for architecture arm64

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine

I'm building a game using Unity (5.6.2). When I build out to Xcode, I get an error regarding CoreServices.

The error is as follows:

> ```
> ld: warning: arm64 function not 4-byte aligned: ltmp0 from /Users/User/Documents/untitled folder/Builds/DriveThrough_205_FB/Libraries/libiPhone-lib.a(unwind_test_arm64.o)
> ld: warning: arm64 function not 4-byte aligned: _unwind_tester from /Users/User/Documents/untitled folder/Builds/DriveThrough_205_FB/Libraries/libiPhone-lib.a(unwind_test_arm64.o)
> ld: framework not found CoreServices for architecture arm64
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
> ```

Has anyone run into this?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Yes. I updated my Unity and it fixed everything. I didn't want to do that, but it needed to be done.

Comment: This is almost always because you are using a wrong version of Xcode. Use the one recommended for your current Unity version. You can choose which one to use (from your installed versions) in Build Settings.

Comment: @AndersEmil Where can I see Xcode version recommended for my Unity version?